# Protractor click method on anchor is not working

Tags: html, protractor

I have an HTML page with an header bar of this type:

```
<div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul ng-if="navMap.main" class="nav navbar-nav ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in navMap.main">
    <li ng-if="item.items &amp;&amp; item.items.length > 0" class="dropdown ng-scope">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle ng-binding" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
          <i ng-if="item.iconClass &amp;&amp; item.iconClass !== ''" class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></i>
          Documentazione
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
        <li ng-repeat="child in item.items" ng-class="{divider:child.divider, 'dropdown-section':child.section}" class="ng-scope">
          <a ng-if="!child.section &amp;&amp; !child.divider" href="#" ng-click="navigate(child)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            Introduzione
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="navMap.main" class="nav navbar-nav ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in navMap.main">
    <li ng-if="item.items &amp;&amp; item.items.length > 0" class="dropdown ng-scope">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle ng-binding" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
          Funzionalità 
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li ng-repeat="child in item.items" ng-class="{divider:child.divider, 'dropdown-section':child.section}" class="ng-scope">
          <a ng-if="!child.section &amp;&amp; !child.divider" href="#" ng-click="navigate(child)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
            Nuovo Ordine
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul ng-if="navMap.right" class="nav navbar-nav pull-right ng-scope">
    <li ng-if="!item.items" ng-hide="item.items" class="ng-scope">
      <a href="#" ng-click="navigate(item)" class="ng-binding"></a>
    </li>
    <li ng-if="item.items &amp;&amp; item.items.length > 0" role="presentation" class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in navMap.right">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="flag-icon flag-icon-it"></span>
        <span class="ng-binding">Cambia</span>
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li nf-if="item.navigationMode.toUpperCase() === 'CHANGELOCALE'" ng-repeat="child in item.items" role="presentation" ng-class="{disabled: configuration.langId === child.locale } " class="ng-scope disabled">
          <a href="" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-click="changeLanguage(child.locale)" class="ng-binding">Italiano</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And I want to build a Protractor test that selects a particular item of one of the lists contained into the header bar. Each item of these lists redirects to another html, clicking simply on it. I am able to select correctly, with a test, an item of a list (I see, in debug mode, the selection of the correct item) but when I simulate the click, with the click() method of Protractor, nothing happens. The test ends successfully but I don't see the redirect to the selected page.

An example code of this selection is:

```
// Opens on Documentation Menu -> IT SUCCEEDS AND I SEE THE MENU OPENED
$$('li.dropdown:nth-child(1)').get(0).$('a:nth-child(1)').click();
// Choosing Introduction -> NOTHING HAPPENS
$$('li.dropdown:nth-child(1)').get(0).$('ul li:nth-child(2) a:nth-child(1)').click();
```

There are other Protractor's instructions to simulate the click on an anchor tag? Is there something wrong into my code or something missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to approach it this way:

- click the `ul` element to open up the list
- locate the link element by text

The code:

```
$("#navbarCollapse").click();

// by link text
element(by.linkText("Documentazione")).click();

// or by partial link text
element(by.partialLinkText("Documentazione")).click();
```

---

There are also other things to try:

- [scroll into view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) of the element before clicking it

  ```
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", elm.getWebElement());
  ```
- click "through javascript"

  ```
  browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elm.getWebElement());
  ```
- move to element and then click

  ```
  browser.actions().mouseMove(elm).click().perform();
  ```

Comment: did not work on my case, i tried all of given sample but not worked.
All of your given code was working under `repl` environment. But not working when i put it on file.

Comment: @ji-ruh that's okay, consider making a separate question providing as much details as you can. Please throw me a link here too. Thanks!